# Access: Min function error on report page header

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to get the min() and max() date of the current query to display on the Page Header section.
My textbox is as follows

```
="Range date: " & Min([myDate]) & " to " & Max([myDate])
```

I am getting the **#Error** message on Access 2010 (MS Access 2003 file format, .mdb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. AFAIK, you can't use those in the page header, but you can use them in a group header/footer and in report header/footer. And you can force new page in a group headre/footer.
2. Otherwise, you will need a report level variable that you increment in the Detail_Format section, and that you reset in the PageHeaderSection_Format.
3. You could also have a control in the page header that refers to the one in the group header. That might be the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks!
I put a textbox with the min and max functions in the report header as invisible with the can shrink option and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

In the page header, you will need DMin and DMax, as far as I recall.

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159048(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: So I would need to send the open report criteria as an argument and add that to the DMin and Dmax?

Answer (score 2):

If I needed this, I'd tend to put it in the report's Recordsource, and then the values would be available anywhere in the report.